# Execute jQuery.click on a selector that contains multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, liquid

I have 2 identic buttons with the id of "data-side-remove":
I also have the following jQuery function

```js
    $('#data-side-remove').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('.line-item-info').slideUp("slow");
      window.location.href = $(this).attr("data-href-remove");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button
        id="data-side-remove"
        class="plus-box"
        data-href-remove="/cart/change?line={{ forloop.index }}&amp;quantity=0"
        type="button"
        name="button">x</button>
```

but for some reason, the code is working fine just for the first of the two button. Then, once its disappeared thanks to the the `slideUp` function, the code is working also for the second button, and so on. I guess it's something related to the fact that once its selected, `$('#data-side-remove')` becomes an array, and the function is just working on the first element of the array. What is the best way to get around this?

Comment: `id` of  HTML element in `document` should be unique, use `class` instead

Comment: both the buttons are having same id? Please use separate ids or use class instead

Comment: Can you post your full HTML which you are sliding up.? What's the issue here

Comment: @guest271314 newbie spotted, you are right sir. thanks

Comment: you need to use different id for each button or create javascript function and add onClick attribute in button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The $(this) will pull the href for the unique plus-box you clicked

```js
    $('.plus-box').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('.line-item-info').slideUp("slow");
      window.location.href = $(this).attr("data-href-remove");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button
        id="data-side-remove"
        class="plus-box"
        data-href-remove="/cart/change?line={{ forloop.index }}&amp;quantity=0"
        type="button"
        name="button">x</button>
```

Comment: I cannot use that class in the context of my project, but yes, the problem is that I was using id instead of classes for selections